# Object disappear from Scene

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I use SceneKit to construct a 3D Scene, which contains a few object. I convert all the COLLADA file and OBJ file to SCN file. Then I use a blank SCN file to put all the object together.

It looks fine in SceneEditor. And it runs on iPad. Everything looks exactly like it was in the SceneEditor.

Then I come up with some idea with the scale of one object. I change it in the property bar. It looks nice at the SceneEditor. And I tried to run it again.

Then boooom.

There was only one object left in the scene. Everything was gone. I can see all the object on SceneEditor. They just not show up on my iPad.
This happens all the time -- after I change any property of any object on the scene, the scene went wrong.

So far I was trying to build a new SCN file again with all those objects. But as the project gets bigger this might be a nightmare.
What is going on? Do you guys have any solution?

UPDATE:

I've notice that the Full Path of the normal SCN files I add in the scene look like: "/xxx.scn". But after some editing, it automatically changed to "xxx.scn" without slash. I think this may be the reason why objects disappear. The wrong path leads to nil and BANG.

Everytime when I use "Quick View" it will automatically change the Full Path. Even if I don't do anything.

I tried to relocate the file but the Full Path stay with no slash. PLS someone help me with it.